# M/Monit proxy/redirection

Tags: proxy, monit

I have monit running on a set of compute nodes on a private network. These nodes do not have access to the M/Monit host. But the compute nodes are connected to a compute server which again have access to the M/Monit host. Is there any M/Monit proxy that I can install on the compute server which redirects the status to the M/Monit host. 
Thanks Tore Nilsen

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is any proxy system special for this case. You might just want to use nginx or apache's httpd.

Examples:

#### Nginx

```
server {
    listen 9247;
    server_name my_proxy_host.local;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://my-mmonit-host/;
    }
}
```

#### Apache httpd

```
<VirtualHost *:9247>
    ServerName  my_proxy_host.local
    ProxyPass   "/" "https://my-mmonit-host/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Both examples create a virtual host `my_proxy_host.local` that listens to port `9247` and proxies all requests to *"your"* remote host `https://my-mmonit-host/`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
This works fine when monit agents sends data to MMonit. But if I want to e.g stop a service on a monit host behind the proxy from the MMonit GUI, I cannot find any solution.

Comment: Oh. You are absolutely right... I didn't think about the "way back"... But since HTTP is stateless, it'll be a hard job if no proxy is supplied by Tildeslash (= org behind m?monit).